# Nimbus look and feel. Change many colors

Tags: java, swing, colors, look-and-feel, nimbus

I am customizing the nimbus LAF colors to my taste.

There are some colors that are used in many controls. For example Color (214,217,223) is used in many controls as background color. [(see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary)

I want to replace that color IN ALL controls. In order to do this I have to use something like this:

```
   UIManager.put("FileChooser.background", new Color(59, 13, 255));
   UIManager.put("TextPane.background", new Color(59, 13, 255));
   UIManager.put("FormattedTextField.background", new Color(59, 13, 255));
```

(as it is described here:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/color.html)

Is there a way to loop around the UIManager Nimbus defaults, and when a color (in my case (214,217,223)) is found REPLACE it with my color of choise, so that I will not have to place a UIManager.put("... ); statement for each control?

Comment: by default are used primary and secondary color, but not all Colors is possible to change, has effects on the screen, in java7 (bug, intention ...)

Comment: I can replace primary "control" color with a color of my choice, but I cannot replace "background" color (secondary). Is that the possible bug you are talking about?

Comment: see my [post to similair question about](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22837833/714968)